# Configure gpupdate /force in .bat for startup clientwide?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am observing in our network (30+ Windows clients) late Refreshing of the Group Policies. Sometimes it last 1 to 2 days for Changes on the GPs taking effect.

As I was an Administrator at our university I saw that our admin forced the client machines to execute a .bat with **gpupdate /force** during startup.

I would like to hear **your opinion** to adopt this bat as Microsoft had something in mind to not let the DC members let the GPOs refresh everytime during startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the users GPO are applied during the opening of a session and the computer GPO are applied during boot.

Moreover, The GPO are periodicaly updated by your system.

If you want to follow the delay during these updates, you can look at yours events logs here : `windows > Group Policy > Operationnal`

In this log you will read the next update for yours computer's and user's GPO with the log `id 5315`.

The log `id 5126` will show you if the download of the GPO is or not succeded.

And the `5312` will show you the applicables GPO like a `gpresult`.

For the script which execute a gpupdate, it's not necessary. The computer updates his GPO during boot. So you will execute ypurs GPO two times.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do such thing.
In order to achieve what you're looking for, you need to setup a GPOs refresh interval GPO.

[Group Policy refresh interval for computers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940895.aspx)